# How to share the direction of the company

Tags: google-maps

I am working as the event coordinator of the company (https://bileeta.com/ ). I need send google map link to the clients embedded in my email how to do that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Share or embed map" feature of Google Maps to produce a shareable link.

Read the guide here : https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361